# Gradle - ear file with war file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle

It works with ear file we build with Maven. Using Gradle, I have an EAR (MyEnterpriseApp) file with a WAR (Myweb) and set of jar files in the root folder. When we deploy it is fine no problem. When the applicatin starts it throws a compound class loader for a class (com.test.mypackage.MyClass) that is available in the one of the jars. We are using Websphere 6.1 on windows.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out my self, using **deploy** and **earlib** together will cause this problem.
Now I am using only deploy with runtime dependencies in war gradle file. For now it solved the problem. If any of you have better idea than this, always welcome.